# How to Batching ESPER EPL events

Tags: esper

I'm trying to batch Notification events like this and I'm getting one Notifications event with a single notification event. Can anyone help me?

Thnks in advance.

Relevant Statements

```
INSERT INTO Notification SELECT d.id as id,a.stationId as stationId,d.firebaseToken as firebaseToken, d.position as devicePos,a.location as stationPos,a.levelNumber as levelNumber,a.levelName as levelName FROM AirQualityAlert.win:time(3sec) as a, device.win:time(3sec) as d WHERE d.position.distance(a.location) < 300

INSERT INTO Notifications SELECT * FROM Notification.std:groupwin(id).win:time_batch(20sec) for grouped_delivery(id)
```

Comment: Listeners receive an array of events. Perhaps your code doesn't look at  the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution delivers a row per 'id' that contain a column with the list of events.

```
create context Batch20Sec start @now end after 20 sec;
context Batch20Sec select id, window(*) as data 
from Notifications#keepall 
group by id 
output all when terminated;
```

I think that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to try that and comment back the results.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks